# Missing foo.c. Using gcc 4.5 in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Im trying to implement OpenMP in Ubuntu 11.04 which I'm running in a virtual machine.
These are the steps which I followed:

1st step=> **sudo apt-get install build-essential**

2nd step=> **sudo apt-get install gcc 4.5**

And now when I run the command for implementing OpenMP (If this is NOT the right command please let me know) the output is:

**ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gcc -fopenmp foo.c

gcc: foo.c: No such file or directory

gcc: no input files**

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a murky concept of what is involved in "implementing" OpenMP. You need to write a program which uses OpenMP (for which `foo.c` is a placeholder) in order to use the library.

Comment: Yes,you are right I really DO cause Ive been using Ubuntu only for two months and OpenMP is a quite NEW concept. Can you please help me to make it more clear? As for the foo.c I don't know if there is one,so I can NOT go on... :S

Comment: It seems that you're not yet familiar with Linux C programming in general. Get a handle on that first before you tackle OpenMP.

Comment: Yes BUT you see I have a project which my profesor gave me so I have to FINISH it! I have no other choice,it's not up to me...:/

Comment: Let me reduce this to a simple question: Do you know how to program in C? IF YOU DO: Write a C program which uses OpenMP, save it, and use its filename instead of "foo.c". IF YOU DO NOT: You cannot complete this project. Get in touch with your professor and inform him of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

To make use of OpenMP in your C code, there are two steps:

1. Use one of OpenMP's [`#pragma`](http://openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1-CCard.pdf) statements in your code where appropriate.
2. Compile with `-fopenmp`.

Also, I can't help but notice that your installation line is a bit sketchy - to install gcc, you only need to do `sudo apt-get install gcc` (this will pull a recent version for you), and to install OpenMP, you would need to do `sudo apt-get install libgomp1`.  If you want a specific version, you would have to make sure that `gcc-4.5` is in Ubuntu 11.04's repositories, which I'm not 100% sure it is.

Comment: Ubuntu software center>>GNU C compiler>>Details>>Version:4:4.5.2-1ubuntu3 (gcc). It seems to me that gcc 4.5 it's not the problem

Comment: Gotcha.  I've fixed my install line to include `libgomp`.

Comment: you mean sudo apt-get install libgomp ?

Comment: @Anita7:  Be sure to read my revised *answer*, not the *comment*.

Comment: This is the output:

**Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree 
      
Reading state information... Done

libgomp1 is already the newest version
.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 259 not upgraded.**

Comment: So OpenMP is installed in your VM.  GCC should be too from your earlier comment.  Now, make sure that the file you're compiling actually exists - the error you're getting seems to be that it doesn't exist.